# Old C# projects not running in Microsoft visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I last downloaded and used Microsoft visual studio 2017 for a C# class back in the spring. I have since opened and loaded an old project today and I get this when running it:

“the current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 2.0. Either target .NET Core 1.1 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 2.0."

Any ideas as to why this is happening? When I open and run my c++ projects from the summer everything runs fine.

Thank you!

Comment: .NETCore is moving fast, much much faster than C++.  Use Project > Properties > Application tab.  High odds you need to pick 2.1 from the "Target framework" combo.  While you are at it, use Help > About to document your question properly with the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like you will have to go to this Microsoft page and choose and install .NET Core SDK you need:

[.NET Core 2.0 downloads](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/dotnet-core/2.0)

Also it's good thing if you install updates in Visual Studio 2017 - check for the notifications flag in upper right corner of VS 2017.

Comment: Excellent, I will try this when I get home from work - I am hoping it’s pretty straightforward on getting everything configured, I am still learning my way around these things. Thank you for taking the time to answer.